# Body and html with 100% height doesn't expand with child div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my website:
http://iguanawebb.se

I want the website to always cover the browser window vertically. I've set the body, html and #wrapper to height: 100%; and that gets the job done.

However, if I add enough content on a page to go past my browser windows height. The body, html and wrapper won't expand with the content. That makes the content to go outside of the body, html and wrapper. I'm on a 13" macbook screen the page "SERVICE, SUPPORT OCH PROVMONTAGE" looks just the way I want it because there's not enough content to go past my browser window's height.

If I click on "OM OSS" the problem appears because there's more content. I've been searching on google and every forum for a solution for the past 2 days but I can't find a solution. Do I need some kind of javascript or something?

Comment: What happens when you use `min-height:100%;`?

Comment: @user3008011 I'd say that's a solution in itself. Post it as an answer!

Comment: @user3008011 Yeah I did the same thing already created a fiddle with an answer.

Comment: @Ruddy : no cookies for you then :p

Comment: @NoobEditor I don't need cookies, I have Jaffa Cakes. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` and `background` from `#left` and `#right`. Add this code to your css:

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    oveflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    background:rgb(26,26,26); 
    background: rgba(26,26,26, .85);
    border-right:670px #313030 solid;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! That helped me a lot. The page "OM OSS" looks just like it is supposed to. But now the "SERVICE, SUPPORT OCH PROVMONTAGE" page is wrong. It also looks like it should, but the page is not 100% there. There's a gap in the bottom on that page. I want the page to be 100% height on that page too.

Comment: I found the solution. I had to add height: 100% to #wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

### HTML

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background: blue;
}
div div {
    width: 20%;
    height: 3000px;
    background: red;
}
```

With the `div` inside:

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/A7ywY/)

Without the `div` inside:

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/A7ywY/1/)

You can remove the inner `div` to see how it reacts. the whole browser screen will have the background. This is due to using `min-height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Posting what I found to fix it is too easy and won't teach you anything. Inside your wrapper there's an element with height 100%. Figure out which element this is and relative to what this 100% is. Once you understand, remove the 100% from that element and your problem is solved

Comment: +1 for teaching the man to fish! CSS becomes much less frustrating after you get a bit of experience on how things fit together.

Comment: I really appreciate the way you answered the question. Unfortunately I still couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to set a min-height so it will be 100% minimum and then expand if necessary.

```
body {
    min-height: 100%; 
}
```

But this is not really what makes you trouble, you have a lots of uncleared floating elements. I tried by removing all the floats and set "min-height" and the body expanded as you want it to.

P.S.: the problem does not come from the way you're sizing the elements even if some are weird. Use the inspector to give it a try.

Comment: Agree, the issue seems to be the uncleared floating elements. You should add a div with `style="clear:both;"` after all the floating divs.